# Evidence for this statement...

Tags: calculus

What evidence can be given for this statement?

"$\forall a > 0 \text{ } \exists P: \forall x \in  (P; +\infty) \rightarrow \sqrt{x + a} \leq \sqrt{x} + 1$"

I already understand the algebraic proof, but I can’t understand this property intuitively, please help.

Comment: I don't understand the statement. The statement is clearly false if we take $x=0$ and $a=\frac12$.

Comment: Most likely, I incorrectly expressed myself due to ignorance of the language, I wanted to say that no matter what the number x > 0 and a = const, there is such an x ​​for which this statement is true from x to +infty

Comment: Check this, please: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/7gn9fechua

Comment: I changed the question, I think now everything will become clearer

Comment: What you write is an obvious consequence of $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x+a} - \sqrt x = 0$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a geometric explanation will help your intuition, please consider the following.

The graph of $f(x)=\sqrt x$ is always increasing, but increasing more and more slowly as $x\to\infty$.  Therefore the interval
$$\sqrt x<y<\sqrt x+1$$
will contain more and more of the graph as $x$ increases.